# VBA - Application.OnKey Not Allowing Reset

Tags: vba, excel

The root of the issue:

When I store the code...

```
Application.OnKey "~", "SomeSub"
```

inside of a Worksheet's method, it works. However, if I reset `Application.OnKey` first, causing the code to look like...

```
Application.OnKey "~"
Application.OnKey "~", "SomeSub"
```

it no longer allows the user to run `SomeSub` using the `Enter` key

Situation:

I have a program that starts with a user login. Instead of the user having to click a button after the username is entered, I'd like to reset the meaning of the `Enter` key to simply run the "SignIn" Sub. Same with the next sheet: after they enter the required info, I'd like the `Enter` key to run the *next* Sub. Therefore, I reassign the meaning of the Enter key. Problem being, after I clear the meaning that time, setting...

```
Application.OnKey "~", "SomeSub"
```

no longer works.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I have since solved my problem with a work-around, by using the `Worksheet_Change` event. But, I'm still curious about why `Application.OnKey` seems to only work once

Comment: Application.OnKey "~",""

Comment: Please reconsider this. This kind of non-standard behavior (inconsistent with Windows apps people use) is likely to first confuse and then frustrate users. Users don't need to click the button, they can tab out giving focus to the button and press enter. It is **almost** always better to stick to UI conventions of the platform.

Comment: Since the users will be on a tablet, they will not have access the `enter` key. The key is actually "pushed" by a bar code scanner that has a return programmed at the end of every bar code. This will be so that the user simply has to scan the code and move on, instead of manually activating the command.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I attempted your suggestion, but no dice

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the problem using Excel 2010 for Windows. If I set the OnKey, it worked. If I cleared the OnKey immediately before I set it, it worked. I suspect you're calling some code that clears it without realizing it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the properties of your "Login"-Button and put the property default to true.

If you now use Enter the button_click event is triggered.

or use this code in the form initialize event

```
CommandButton1.Default = True
```

Comment: Unfortunately, since my program often creates and destroys buttons, I am using Form Controls instead of ActiveX

Comment: I am also talking about the form controls